# Separate web and email host

Tags: email, web, dns, hosting

My client has their domain name (lorem.com) registered with company X which also host their email. I'd like to host their new website with separate hosting company (company Y). I know I need to update the DNS nameservers for their domain name to point to company Y's nameservers. I'm not sure how to handle the email host though. Doing an MX lookup on their domain, currently shows:

> Pref   Hostname
>
> 10     lorem.com
>
> 20     mx2.companyX.com

Do I need to do any updates to the MX record? Also, do I need to add/edit the A record to point to company Y's IP address? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you are migrating only your website from the old hosting company to a new hosting company.

> Do I need to do any updates to the MX record?

**No,** since you want the old server(hosting company) to keep managing your emails, no changes to MX records are required.

> Also, do I need to add/edit the A record to point to company Y's IP address?

**Correct.** All you need is to put in a new A record to company Y's IP. Remember to change the A record for .(root) and www (if www subdomain exists) and any other sub-domains that your website may have (eg. ftp etc.)

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't clear enough on my intention in my original post. The goal is to keep the emails hosted on the original company (company X) and have the new site hosted on the new company Y. To avoid backing up emails and seems like less of a hassle, I should just edit the A record on company X to company Y, correct? Why do I need to update the MX record since the emails are not being moved? Thanks!

Comment: Correct, in that case you'll just need to change the A record in your existing nameserver config. Thanks for clarifying your question.I have corrected the answer.